# logstash and rsyslog sends wrong hostname

Tags: linux, rsyslog, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm setting up a centralised logging system, comprising two VM's.

- Logger, which acts as the central syslog collector (using rsyslog) and Logstash processor; and
- Searcher, which acts as the Elasticsearch and Kibana host.

I have syslogs from my Wifi controller sent to logger, and being filed in /var/log/remote/wificontroller/*.log

Logstash is processing these logs, and they appear in Kibana.

However, they all have the hostname 'logger' not 'wificontroller', when the logs appear in Kibana. How can I have them sent with the correct hostname?

Many thanks,
James

Comment: you may need to massage data as it coming in through logstash' pipeline (filter area)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/filter-plugins.html) step in your config file to [mutate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html) your events during the processing :

```
filter {
  mutate {
    replace => [ "source", "%{wifi_controller}" ]
    }
}
```

I don't know how your events are structured, but if the controllers hostname is not in a specific field, you'll probably have to [dissect](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.2/plugins-filters-dissect.html) or [grok](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) the logs.

Comment: Excellent - did just the job, thanks!